# Spawn camera at fixed position in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to spawn a camera at a fixed position on gazebo. Its there any way to do it without connecting it to a robot?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196485/spawn-camera-at-fixed-position-in-gazebo/) by [h66](https://answers.ros.org/users/20672/h66/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to make an SDF model file that contains the camera plugin and then drag that model into your gazebo world.  If you need the camera higher than the ground plane, you should be able to define the pose in the SDF file.

Actually, here is a Gazebo tutorial that walks you through creating a camera model and adding it to your world.
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=camera_distortion&cat=sensors

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2